# Table disappears after clicking on add button on Livewire

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-livewire, laravel-9

**My Livewire Component**

```php
public $productId;
public $allTariff = [];
public $rowProducts = [];

public function mount()
{
    $this->rowProducts = Products::all();

    $this->allTariff = [
            ['productId' => '', 'basicCharge' => '', 'additionalCharge' => '']
    ];
}

public function addProduct()
{

    $this->allTariff[] = ['productId' => '', 'basicCharge' => '', 'additionalCharge' => ''];
}

public function render()
{
    $rowProducts = Products::all();
    return view('livewire.admin.admin-add-tariffs-component', ['rowProducts'=>$rowProducts)->layout('layouts.admin.base');
}
```

**My View File**

```html
<!-- Begin Page Content -->
<div class="container-fluid">
    <!-- Page Heading -->
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-8">
            <div class="card shadow mb-4">
                <div class="card-header py-3">
                    <h6 class="m-0 font-weight-bold text-primary">Add Tariff</h6>
                </div>
                <div class="card-body">
                  <form wire:submit.prevent="storeTariff">
                    @csrf
                    <div class="form-row">
                        <!-- Default input -->
                        <div class="form-group col-md-8">
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Tariff Name" wire:model="tariffName" >
                        </div>
                    </div><hr>

                    <div class="card">
                        <div class="card-header">
                            <h6 class="text-primary">Products, Basic and Weight Charges</h6>
                        </div>
                        <div class="card-body">
                            <table class="table" id="products_table">
                                <thead>
                                    <tr>
                                        <th>Product</th>
                                        <th>Basic Charge</th>
                                        <th>Weight Charge</th>
                                        <th></th>
                                    </tr>
                                </thead>
                                <tbody>

                                    @foreach ($allTariff as $index => $value)
                                        <tr>
                                            <td>
                                                <select name="allTariff[{{$index}}][productId]"
                                                    wire:model="allTariff.{{ $index }}.productId"
                                                    class="custom-select custom-select-sm form-control form-control-sm">
                                                    @foreach ($rowProducts as $product)
                                                    <option value="{{ $product->id }}">
                                                        {{ $product->product_name }}
                                                    </option>
                                                    @endforeach
                                                </select>
                                            </td>
                                            <td>
                                                <input type="text" class="form-control form-control-user" name="allTariff[{{$index}}][basicCharge]" placeholder="Basic Charge" wire:model="allTariff.{{ $index }}.basicCharge" required>
                                            </td>
                                            <td>
                                                <input type="text" class="form-control form-control-user" name="allTariff[{{$index}}][additionalCharge]" placeholder="Weight Charge" wire:model="allTariff.{{ $index }}.additionalCharge" required>
                                            </td>
                                        </tr>
                                    @endforeach
                                </tbody>
                            </table>

                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-md-12">
                                    <button class="btn btn-sm btn-secondary"
                                        wire:click.prevent="addProduct">+ Add Another Product</button>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <hr>

                    {{-- <div class="form-row">
                        <div class="form-group col-md-3"> --}}
                            <button type="submit" class="form-control btn btn-small btn-primary">Add
                                Tariff</button>
                        {{-- </div>
                    </div> --}}
                </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<!-- /.container-fluid -->
```

*Every time I click on the add tariff button [this photo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2B6GL.png) it give the blank page on [this photo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PaEDo.png), but on console an html response is given.

I have tried a couple methods and tricks still no way out, just stuck for days*

I have already include the livewire `@livewireStyles` and `@livewireScripts`, and i can't find an answer anywhere else cause i don't see any question that match my problem, and i'm kinda new to livewire

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When using Livewire, there are a few things you need to be aware of. Due to the nature of how Livewire updates the page, there are some structural rules you need to follow.

The first and probably most important thing here, is that every Livewire-component view should only consist of *one* root element. And this includes comments!

If we count the root elements in your view, there are three - a comment, a div, and then another comment. So the first thing I did here, was to move the comments inside that div.

```html
<div class="container-fluid">
    <!-- Begin Page Content -->
    <!-- Page Heading -->
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-8">
            <div class="card shadow mb-4">
                <div class="card-header py-3">
                    <h6 class="m-0 font-weight-bold text-primary">Add Tariff</h6>
                </div>
                <div class="card-body">
                    <form wire:submit.prevent="storeTariff">
                        @csrf
                        <div class="form-row">
                            <!-- Default input -->
                            <div class="form-group col-md-8">
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Tariff Name"
                                    wire:model="tariffName">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <hr>

                        <div class="card">
                            <div class="card-header">
                                <h6 class="text-primary">Products, Basic and Weight Charges</h6>
                            </div>
                            <div class="card-body">
                                <table class="table" id="products_table">
                                    <thead>
                                        <tr>
                                            <th>Product</th>
                                            <th>Basic Charge</th>
                                            <th>Weight Charge</th>
                                            <th></th>
                                        </tr>
                                    </thead>
                                    <tbody>

                                        @foreach ($allTariff as $index => $value)
                                            <tr>
                                                <td>
                                                    <select name="allTariff[{{ $index }}][productId]"
                                                        wire:model="allTariff.{{ $index }}.productId"
                                                        class="custom-select custom-select-sm form-control form-control-sm">
                                                        @foreach ($rowProducts as $product)
                                                            <option value="{{ $product->id }}">
                                                                {{ $product->product_name }}
                                                            </option>
                                                        @endforeach
                                                    </select>
                                                </td>
                                                <td>
                                                    <input type="text" class="form-control form-control-user"
                                                        name="allTariff[{{ $index }}][basicCharge]"
                                                        placeholder="Basic Charge"
                                                        wire:model="allTariff.{{ $index }}.basicCharge" required>
                                                </td>
                                                <td>
                                                    <input type="text" class="form-control form-control-user"
                                                        name="allTariff[{{ $index }}][additionalCharge]"
                                                        placeholder="Weight Charge"
                                                        wire:model="allTariff.{{ $index }}.additionalCharge"
                                                        required>
                                                </td>
                                            </tr>
                                        @endforeach
                                    </tbody>
                                </table>

                                <div class="row">
                                    <div class="col-md-12">
                                        <button class="btn btn-sm btn-secondary" wire:click.prevent="addProduct">+ Add Another Product</button>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <hr>

                        {{-- <div class="form-row">
                        <div class="form-group col-md-3"> --}}
                        <button type="submit" class="form-control btn btn-small btn-primary">Add
                            Tariff</button>
                        {{-- </div>
                    </div> --}}
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- /.container-fluid -->
</div>
```

Then another thing I would recommend that you look into is using `wire:key` on the `tr` element inside your table-loop, and on the `option` element inside your inner loop. The value to `wire:key` should always be unique to that particular row, so using `$loop->index` is not generally advised. You can generate a dummy-ID for each record that you add to your array, which sole purpose is to track the individual row. Here's how, see the `wire:key` I added in the template,

```html
<div class="container-fluid">
    <!-- Begin Page Content -->
    <!-- Page Heading -->
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-8">
            <div class="card shadow mb-4">
                <div class="card-header py-3">
                    <h6 class="m-0 font-weight-bold text-primary">Add Tariff</h6>
                </div>
                <div class="card-body">
                    <form wire:submit.prevent="storeTariff">
                        @csrf
                        <div class="form-row">
                            <!-- Default input -->
                            <div class="form-group col-md-8">
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Tariff Name"
                                    wire:model="tariffName">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <hr>

                        <div class="card">
                            <div class="card-header">
                                <h6 class="text-primary">Products, Basic and Weight Charges</h6>
                            </div>
                            <div class="card-body">
                                <table class="table" id="products_table">
                                    <thead>
                                        <tr>
                                            <th>Product</th>
                                            <th>Basic Charge</th>
                                            <th>Weight Charge</th>
                                            <th></th>
                                        </tr>
                                    </thead>
                                    <tbody>

                                        @foreach ($allTariff as $index => $value)
                                            <tr wire:key="tariff-{{ $value->wireKey }}">
                                                <td>
                                                    <select name="allTariff[{{ $index }}][productId]"
                                                        wire:model="allTariff.{{ $index }}.productId"
                                                        class="custom-select custom-select-sm form-control form-control-sm">
                                                        @foreach ($rowProducts as $product)
                                                            <option value="{{ $product->id }}" wire:key="product-{{ $product->id }}">
                                                                {{ $product->product_name }}
                                                            </option>
                                                        @endforeach
                                                    </select>
                                                </td>
                                                <td>
                                                    <input type="text" class="form-control form-control-user"
                                                        name="allTariff[{{ $index }}][basicCharge]"
                                                        placeholder="Basic Charge"
                                                        wire:model="allTariff.{{ $index }}.basicCharge" required>
                                                </td>
                                                <td>
                                                    <input type="text" class="form-control form-control-user"
                                                        name="allTariff[{{ $index }}][additionalCharge]"
                                                        placeholder="Weight Charge"
                                                        wire:model="allTariff.{{ $index }}.additionalCharge"
                                                        required>
                                                </td>
                                            </tr>
                                        @endforeach
                                    </tbody>
                                </table>

                                <div class="row">
                                    <div class="col-md-12">
                                        <button class="btn btn-sm btn-secondary" wire:click.prevent="addProduct">+ Add Another Product</button>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <hr>

                        {{-- <div class="form-row">
                        <div class="form-group col-md-3"> --}}
                        <button type="submit" class="form-control btn btn-small btn-primary">Add
                            Tariff</button>
                        {{-- </div>
                    </div> --}}
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- /.container-fluid -->
</div>
```

And then in your component, just generate a unique string

```php
class AdminAddTariffsComponent 
{
    public $productId;
    public $allTariff = [];
    public $rowProducts = [];

    public function mount()
    {
        $this->rowProducts = Products::all();

        $this->addProduct();
    }

    public function addProduct()
    {
        $this->allTariff[] = [
            'productId' => '', 
            'basicCharge' => '', 
            'additionalCharge' => '',
            'wireKey' => \Str::uuid(),
        ];
    }

    public function render()
    {
        return view('livewire.admin.admin-add-tariffs-component')
            ->layout('layouts.admin.base');
    }
}
```